# Curl request equivalent in VB.NET - monday.com API

Tags: vb.net

I need to call a monday.com API to upload a file. Below is the Curl sample given.

curl 
-F query='mutation ($file: File!) { add_file_to_column(file: $file, item_id: 118607269, column_id: "files") { id } }'
-F variables[file]=@/Users/diprobhowmik/screenshots/image.png
-H "Authorization: APIKEYHERE" 
https://api.monday.com/v2/file

I need to convert it to VB.NET.
I'm having problems when attaching file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you are doing so far.

Comment: You should be using an [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netcore-3.1). What `Content-Type` does the server expect?